# EOF error when using "rb"

Tags: python-3.x, pickle

here is my code:

```
authors_file_handler = open(authors_file,'r')
authors = pickle.load(authors_file_handler)
authors_file_handler.close()
```

authors_file is a .pkl file and I have confirmed info that it is not empty.
On using 'rb' or 'r+b' in place of 'r', I get an error:

File "../tools\email_preprocess.py", line 33, in preprocess
    authors = pickle.load(authors_file_handler)
EOFError: Ran out of input

PLease advise on how to handle this error.

Comment: using 'rb' or'r+b' because with 'r' i get the error on the line:

Comment: authors = pickle.load(authors_file_handler)

Comment: that : 'str' does not support a buffer interface.

Comment: If you're getting an EOF error, that means your contents weren't dumped properly... or it could be a dumping in 3 and loading in 2 (check your protocol).

Comment: how to check my protocol?

Comment: did that...got an error that cPickle module doesnt exist so i changed it to: import _pickle as pickle

Comment: I see... my bad, that's a python2 module. I'm really getting my facts wrong here.

Comment: while using 'rb', got the same error: EOFerror: Ran out of input